# How to add Open Telemetry to Angular Universal project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal, open-telemetry

I would like to add Open Telemetry tracing and metrics to my Node.js Angular Universal application.

The problem is that there is no place to put this script from Open Telemetry manual:

```
node --require ./instrumentation.js app.js
```

because the process of serving and building is encapsulated in `@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server` and `@angular-devkit/build-angular:server`

Importing instrumentation.js in project leads to errors such as:

```
./node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-node/node_modules/@opentelemetry/instrumentation/build/esm/platform/node/instrumentation.js:89:29-50 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
./node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-node/node_modules/@opentelemetry/instrumentation/build/esm/platform/node/instrumentation.js:102:20-63 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/USERNAME/projects/project/dist/apps/project/server/jaeger-idl/thrift/jaeger.thrift'
```